# Can an EXEC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL) on dyld my fault?

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, dyld

I'm developing this app that worked beautifully on dev box and test box alike with osx 10.8.
Test box is significantly older hardware but same software setup as dev box.

- Dev Box: intel core i7
- Test Box: intel core 2 duo

Upon upgrade to OSX 10.9 Mavericks on both machines, I'm getting an **EXEC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(SIGILL)** failure on my test box with an error report that seems to suggest a problem with 10.9.

Is it possible that it's something I did or should I nag Apple to fix their Os?

I have tried all the **DYLD_PRINT_*** env variables to see if I get some clues, but it just fails with no abnormal or indicative messages.

Any Ideas as to what It could be or where to look further/deeper?
Your interpretation of this trace is also welcome.

```
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
/Volumes/juan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/****/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/libprotobuf-lite.8.dylib

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libprotobuf-lite.8.dylib        0x0000000103d18bc4 _GLOBAL__I_a + 4
1   dyld                            0x00007fff69423c2e ImageLoaderMachO::doModInitFunctions(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 268
2   dyld                            0x00007fff69423dba ImageLoaderMachO::doInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 40
3   dyld                            0x00007fff69420a62 ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) + 308
4   dyld                            0x00007fff694209eb ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) + 189
5   dyld                            0x00007fff694208f6 ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) + 54
6   dyld                            0x00007fff694141da dyld::initializeMainExecutable() + 189
7   dyld                            0x00007fff69417560 dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) + 2419
8   dyld                            0x00007fff6941327b dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*, unsigned long*) + 477
9   dyld                            0x00007fff6941305e _dyld_start + 54

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000001  rbx: 0x0000000103d18bc0  rcx: 0x00007fff5c425cd0  rdx: 0x00007fff5c425c78
  rdi: 0x0000000000000001  rsi: 0x00007fff5c425c68  rbp: 0x00007fff5c4240c0  rsp: 0x00007fff5c4240c0
   r8: 0x00007fff69446178   r9: 0x00007fff5c424000  r10: 0x00007fff9abcbc70  r11: 0x00007fff961c02aa
  r12: 0x0000000000000000  r13: 0x00007fff694460b0  r14: 0x00007fff6944eb28  r15: 0x0000000103d20310
  rip: 0x0000000103d18bc4  rfl: 0x0000000000010246  cr2: 0x0000000103d18bc0

Logical CPU:     1
Error Code:      0x00000000
Trap Number:     6
```

Answer (score 3):

So I found the problem.

My libraries were built using homebrew. By default homebrew optimizes for native architecture, resulting in machine instructions that don't work on older machines.

to prevent brew from building processsor-speciffic optimisations you must

**brew install --build-bottle protobuf** ( or your specific lib )

Comment: You may also want to try --build-from-source